# I'm getting the wrong data when using doctrine in symfony

Tags: mysql, doctrine, symfony

I'm trying to build a SQL query using doctrine. Here's my code snippet:

```
/**
 * @Route("/db", name="user_skill_testing")
 */
public function dbTest()
{
    //all skills for user

    $userName = "Jelle";
    $user = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:User')
        ->findOneByFirstname($userName);

    echo "userId: ".$user->getId()."<br />";

    $userSkills = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:Userskill')->findById($user->getId());

    $proficiencies = array();
    foreach ($userSkills as $userSkill) {
        array_push($proficiencies, $userSkill);

        echo $userSkill->getId();
        echo "-";
        echo $userSkill->getProficiency()->getId();
        echo "<br />";
    }

    var_dump($userSkills);

    $html = "<html><body>".$user->getFirstname()."<br /><br />"."</body></html>";
    return new Response($html);
}
```

It returns the following webpage(screenshot):
[image]

When I look at the queries it ran...:

[image]

...and rerun them...:

[image]

...I get a very different result. :(
I have no idea why, can anyone help me out?
thank you!

Edit: using this code to build the query reproduces the same result.

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the findById method from the Userskill repository?

Comment: It's automatically generated by symfony. I can't even look it up.

Comment: But the default EntityRepository does not contain this method. Please add this to your controller and tell us the output: var_dump(get_class($this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Userskill')));

Comment: This is the output you requested: http://i.imgur.com/FqPV3h6.jpg

I think the method does exist be default. see: http://i.imgur.com/zsNTPYY.jpg at http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html

Comment: Oh well, the EntityRepository implements a __call method, somehow I never realized that. In that case, can you show us the mapping information of the Userskill entity?

Comment: do you mean this: http://i.imgur.com/F8DHeuX.jpg
or this:http://i.imgur.com/37Op7w1.png
?

Comment: The first one. But it looks good too. I'm running out of ideas now. Did you execute the query on the same database which symfony uses? Otherwise I don't know how to help you any further, unfortunately. :-/

Comment: I am 99% sure yes.
thanks for taking the time to try to help me

Comment: edit: I just added a user to the database and verified it's exitence in php. now I'm 100% sure

Comment: The `UserSkill::$id` === `User::$id`? you're sure it doesn't have its own autogenerated id? Maybe best to add mappings to the question.

Comment: It does not, but why would that matter?
http://i.imgur.com/FuoEmyn.jpg

Comment: So there's no relational mapping between `User`and `UserSkill`? you set `UserSkill`'s $id manually?

Comment: yes.
In the images above you can see that they do contain valid values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having MySql generate the many-to-many relationship helped doctrine generate the correct entities.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies with your PK on `UserSkill`. When doctrine Hydrates, it will assume entities with the same primary key, are the same entity, ignoring rows with the same PK if one has already been hydrated.

Since your `Userskill::$id` is not unique, only the first one will be hydrated, subsequent rows with the same id, will get a reference to the same entity.

To solve this, you need to [create a compound key](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html), consisting of the `id` **and** the proficiencyId.

In you use-case though, this will make things unpractical. So I would just replace your manual id on `Userskill` with an actual one-to-many relation from `User`to `Userskill`...

Comment: This seems like the way to go!
I did define a compound key in my database, but doctrine didn't get that I think.
I'll let you know if I fixed it after my noon break
thank you!

Comment: doctrine does not read any database definitions. you must define it in your mappings or doctrine won't know it's there.

Comment: Even when I just querry this table for all records I still get false information. So I doubt the source of the problem lies in the relations